# Can't install haskell platform because of libgl1-mesa

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude, haskell

When trying to install haskell platform using `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 haskell-platform : Depends: libghc-gluraw-dev (>= 1.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-gluraw-dev (< 1.3.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-glut-dev (>= 2.4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-glut-dev (< 2.4.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-opengl-dev (>= 2.8.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-opengl-dev (< 2.8.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
```

When trying to do the same using `sudo aptitude install haskell-platform`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri but 10.2.0~git20140424.fd92346c-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy is installed.
                              Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but 10.2.0~git20140424.fd92346c-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
                              Conflicts: libgl1:i386 which is a virtual package.
                              Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx but 10.2.0~git20140315.2e361160-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy is installed.
                              Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but 10.2.0~git20140315.2e361160-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa but 10.2.0~git20140315.2e361160-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy is installed.
                            Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 but 10.2.0~git20140315.2e361160-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy is installed.
 xserver-xorg : Conflicts: xorg-renamed-package which is a virtual package.
```

I think the `libgl1-mesa` is to blame, but I'm not sure. I have `libegl1-mesa` already installed on my system, but the version is `10.2.0~git20140315.2e361160-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy`. It seems that haskell needs another version, but I can't remove existing one, because there are dependencies on it.

`Aptitude` also proposed multiple "solutions", but they are quite radical. One of them was to remove `wine`, `skype`, `xorg`, etc.

Result of `apt-cache policy haskell-platform`:

```
haskell-platform:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2013.2.0.0.debian3
  Version table:
     2013.2.0.0.debian3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Result of `apt-cache policy libghc-gluraw-dev`:

```
libghc-gluraw-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.0.0-2
  Version table:
     1.3.0.0-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Result of `sudo apt-get install libghc-gluraw-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libghc-gluraw-dev : Depends: libghc-openglraw-dev-1.3.0.0-3fbff
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Result of `apt-cache policy libghc-openglraw-dev-1.3.0.0-3fbff`:

```
libghc-openglraw-dev-1.3.0.0-3fbff:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Result of `sudo apt-get install libghc-openglraw-dev-1.3.0.0-3fbff`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libghc-openglraw-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                                 libgl-dev
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29334/discussion-between-a-b-and-damluar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, a lot had to be clarified. Read [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29334/discussion-between-a-b-and-damluar).

The solution is, use `aptitude` to downgrade the package `libgl1-mesa-glx`. We had no luck with `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx=10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4`.

```
sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-glx=10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

And after this brutal intervention you have to reinstall your desktop environment, Xorg and Nvidia drivers,