# Any suggestions on installing the haskell-platform or stack in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to install `haskell-platform` and I am getting the following unmet dependencies.

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 haskell-platform : Depends: ghc (>= 7.6.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ghc (< 7.6.3+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-async-dev (>= 2.0.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-async-dev (< 2.0.1.4+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-attoparsec-dev (>= 0.10.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-attoparsec-dev (< 0.10.4.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-case-insensitive-dev (>= 1.0.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-case-insensitive-dev (< 1.1.0.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-cgi-dev (>= 3001.1.8.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-cgi-dev (< 3001.1.8.3+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-fgl-dev (>= 5.4.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-fgl-dev (< 5.4.2.4+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-gluraw-dev (>= 1.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-gluraw-dev (< 1.3.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-glut-dev (>= 2.4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-glut-dev (< 2.4.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-hashable-dev (>= 1.2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-hashable-dev (< 1.2.1.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-haskell-src-dev (>= 1.0.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-haskell-src-dev (< 1.0.1.5+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-html-dev (>= 1.0.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-html-dev (< 1.0.1.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-http-dev (>= 1:4000.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-http-dev (< 1:4000.2.8+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-hunit-dev (>= 1.2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-hunit-dev (< 1.2.5.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-mtl-dev (>= 2.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-mtl-dev (< 2.1.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-network-dev (>= 2.4.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-network-dev (< 2.4.1.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-opengl-dev (>= 2.8.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-opengl-dev (< 2.8.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-parallel-dev (>= 3.2.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-parallel-dev (< 3.2.0.3+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-parsec3-dev (>= 3.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-parsec3-dev (< 3.1.3+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-primitive-dev (>= 0.5.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-primitive-dev (< 0.5.0.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-quickcheck2-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-quickcheck2-dev (< 2.6+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-base-dev (>= 0.93.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-base-dev (< 0.93.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-compat-dev (>= 0.95.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-compat-dev (< 0.95.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-posix-dev (>= 0.95.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-regex-posix-dev (< 0.95.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-split-dev (>= 0.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-split-dev (< 0.2.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-stm-dev (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-stm-dev (< 2.4.2+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-syb-dev (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-syb-dev (< 0.4.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-text-dev (>= 0.11.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-text-dev (< 0.11.3.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-transformers-dev (>= 0.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-transformers-dev (< 0.3.0.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-unordered-containers-dev (>= 0.2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-unordered-containers-dev (< 0.2.3.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-vector-dev (>= 0.10.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-vector-dev (< 0.10.0.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-xhtml-dev (>= 3000.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-xhtml-dev (< 3000.2.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-zlib-dev (>= 0.5.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libghc-zlib-dev (< 0.5.4.1+) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ghc-haddock but it is not going to be installed

These dependencies are different from the other questions,  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676227/cant-install-haskell-platform-because-of-libgl1-mesa)  and  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553261/when-i-try-to-install-the-haskell-platform-on-14-04-i-get-unmet-dependencies) , on this site.

Some packages mentioned in the first  [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676227/cant-install-haskell-platform-because-of-libgl1-mesa)  are also the ones I have come across so I implemented the solution there. However I couldn't get it to work (the same dependencies kept coming up).

Leaving it aside for a moment I tried installing the 
 [haskell stack.](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade.html#ubuntu)  
However it requires me to install the package `libgmp3-dev`. I cannot seem to be able to install it using `synaptic` or `sudo apt-get install`.

I am looking for any suggestions to installing `haskell-platform` or failing that `ghc` compiler on my system. I am running `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Please feel free to edit my question or request any information. 
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can't you download the packages and installed them through dpkg -i ?

Comment: @LnxSlck No,  it gives me "Errors were encountered while processing:"

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: here is the dialogue: `sudo dpkg -i libgmp3-dev`  I get <p> `dpkg: error processing archive libgmp3-dev (--install):` <br>
 `cannot access archive: No such file or directory`<br>
`Errors were encountered while processing:`<br>
 `libgmp3-dev` </p>

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text and apply code formatting.

Comment: Have you downloaded the package libgmp3-dev ?

Comment: Therein lies the problem as I see it. I seem to have a problem installing libgmp3-dev. It appears wither I need to remove a uncomfortable large number of packages or there is some bug that I need to work around.