# WiFi Problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

#### The Problem:

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was working fine until yesterday morning after login I couldn't get the  wifi in ubuntu stopped to work (see details below) the windows part seems to work just fine. I would like to restore the wifi in ubuntu.

#### Some Background:

The last time everything was fine, I was trying to (unsuccessfully) install `haskell-platform` in ubuntu (see  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726907/any-suggestions-on-installing-the-haskell-platform-or-stack-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1076916_726907) ). I followed the advice  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726907/any-suggestions-on-installing-the-haskell-platform-or-stack-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1076916_726907)  and downgraded my `libgl1-mesa-glx` package. As a result some brutal changes took place and I had to reinstall `Xorg` and `Desktop-Environment`. The problem with network manager started after that so I am guessing this was the source.

As mentioned before, I can access wifi via Windows. I can also access wifi by using a live ubuntu-usb. So, I can install packages to my hdd-ubuntu distribution. This makes me believe that there is no hardware problem and somehow I have deleted some essential packages.

I am a noob in networking issues so most of what I have done (outlined below)  is based on my very limited (and perhaps wacky) understanding and reading through many threads on this site and elsewhere. So it is entirely possible that I have missed something trivial.

#### What I did

I purged and then reinstalled the packages `network-manager`, `resolvconf`; `isc-dhcp-client` and `isc-dhcp-server` packages couple of times.

This doesn't seem to solve the problem.

**My `ifconfig -a` reads:**

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:45:c4:b6:b4:85
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:27488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2028140 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:2028140 (2.0 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:e3:92:b9:ab:c6
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:8e:04:2f:9f
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

**`lshw -C` shows**

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 08:3e:8e:04:2f:9f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-77-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 78:45:c4:b6:b4:85
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)

---

Some other configuration files that I checked were :`/etc/network/interfaces` which reads

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

*I added and then commented out `#auto eth0`, `#iface eth0 inet dhcp`, `#auto wlan0`, `#iface wlan0 inet dhcp` because it didn't solve the problem and just started the message `waiting for network configuration` when booting into ubuntu.*

My `/etc/resolv.conf` reads

`#Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)`
`#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

My `/etc/hosts` reads

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 my-comp
`#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts`
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

and my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` reads

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

My `iwconfig` outputs:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any

          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm

          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

If tried `sudo ifdown wlan0' and 'sudo ifup wlan0' and didn't get any output which makes me think they are ok.

I am looking for any directions that I might take to solve the problem. One possible way out, I think, is to try to transfer all relevant packages from live-usb to my home folder but I am not sure how to go about it....
I would prefer any solution short of a fresh install at this point.

Thank you for your help in advance (and special thanks for any impromptu networking lessons too). I would be happy to put any additional information.

---

**Edit**

Some additional info based on answers/comments.

`rfkill list` output

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A million thanks to  [this question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet)  the problem is a bug in  **libnl**  package (see  [here for details](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735/comments/29) ).

I do not claim any credit for this answer. I am posting it because I myself wasn't aware of this issue (and erroneously thought that the reason was something else) so people doing google search on  **wifi issues on ubuntu**  maynot get directed to that question but they might benefit   [from the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/727462/142405) .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you soft blocked WiFi by accident to check that run

```
rfkill list
```

You there see a list of all wireless devices (wifi, Bluetooth) if you see a `soft blocked: yes` you should run

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

And you should be fine

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ran `rfkill list` and the output didn't indicate a soft-block. I have updated the out put in the question.